# Python - Generating url for date range - Outputs 0 result if year is lower than 2019

Tags: python

I had a struggle for few days now and I really hope that someone here can help me.

I have tried everything to make this work for dates lower than year 2019 and it doesn't want to generate any date in range that is lower than year 2019.

---

You can try to change
tmpTo = '2018-05-31'
to
tmpTo = '2019-05-31'
and it will give output

---

Here is Demo code i made for preview that goes together with much more code:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime
import time

dateFrom = datetime.strptime('2019-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d")
dateTo = datetime.strptime('2019-01-10', "%Y-%m-%d")
plusDAYS = 0
todayPlus1 = dateFrom + timedelta(days=plusDAYS)
datesFromTo = []
visitUrl = []

def autoInput():
    global dateTo
    global dateFrom
    tmpFrom = '2018-05-02'
    tmpTo = '2018-05-31'
    dateFrom = datetime.strptime(tmpFrom, "%Y-%m-%d")
    dateTo = datetime.strptime(tmpTo, "%Y-%m-%d")
    separator = ' * '
    pausa0 = 2
    pausa = 3

autoInput()
print(dateFrom)
print(dateTo)
print('----------------------------')
print('----------------------------')


def createDatesFromTo():
    global datesFromTo
    global todayPlus1
    global plusDAYS
    while dateTo >= todayPlus1:
        todayPlus1 = dateFrom + timedelta(days=plusDAYS)
        datesFromTo.append(todayPlus1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        plusDAYS += 1
        todayPlus1 = dateFrom + timedelta(days=plusDAYS)

createDatesFromTo()
print('PRINTS EVERYTHING LIST IS CONTAINING')
print(datesFromTo)

print('----------------------------')
print('----------------------------')


def createUrlForDates():
    global visitUrl
    #for i in range(len(datesFromTo)): # ORIGINAL
    for i in range(5): # DEMO 5 ITEMS
        tmp = datesFromTo[i]+"&tom="+datesFromTo[i]+""
        visitUrl.append(tmp)


createUrlForDates()
for i in visitUrl:
    print('URL  RESULT ---> www.TEST.com/?from='+i)
```

Comment: If I change ```dateFrom ``` to ```2019-01-01``` it prints ```PRINTS EVERYTHING LIST IS CONTAINING
['2018-05-02', '2018-05-03', '2018-05-04', '2018-05-05', '2018-05-06', '2018-05-07', '2018-05-08', '2018-05-09', '2018-05-10', '2018-05-11', '2018-05-12', '2018-05-13', '2018-05-14', '2018-05-15', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-17', '2018-05-18', '2018-05-19', '2018-05-20', '2018-05-21', '2018-05-22', '2018-05-23', '2018-05-24', '2018-05-25', '2018-05-26', '2018-05-27', '2018-05-28', '2018-05-29', '2018-05-30', '2018-05-31']```

Comment: You need to set the `global` `todayPlus1` inside the `autoinput` function.

Comment: that doesn't change the output. It still gives empty list and same error 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: Do you have any other thots or ideas? I really need this to work and would appreciate if anyone helped